# Servlet : create text file using servlets in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, exception

when i try to create a text file usnig servlet in eclipse it generate an exception `FileNotFound`

```
File file = new File("WebContent/WEB-INF/user.txt");
file.createNewFile();
```

after this the file not found exception throw.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to give the path.

```
File file = new File("user.txt");
file.createNewFile();
```

This will create a file `user.txt` under `Web-Inf`.

Comment: when i do this , the `file.createNewFile();`method return false.

Answer (score 0):

The Exception is because the path does not exists. Use PremGenError's answer for the default location, or If you want to create a new path do `file.mkdirs()`